# What does "relevant research" in this case mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

*True, we still don’t have the acumen to achieve this, but there seems to be no insurmountable technical barrier preventing us from producing superhumans . The main obstacles are the ethical and political objections that have slowed down research on humans. And no matter how convincing the ethical arguments may be, it is hard to see how they can hold back the next step for long, especially if what is at stake is the possibility of prolonging human life indefinitely, conquering incurable diseases, and upgrading our cognitive and emotional abilities. What would happen, for example, if we developed a cure for Alzheimer’s disease that, as a side benefit, could dramatically improve the memories of healthy people? Would anyone be able to halt the **relevant research?***

What does the **relevant** **research**   imply here?

Comment: I added more context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here ***[relevant](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/relevant)*** means:

> - correct or suitable for a particular purpose:
>
>   - *plans to make schooling more relevant to life beyond school*.

Cambridge Dictionary

So the *relevant research* is the reseach that will probably lead to the scientific advancements the author is referring to in the article.